# Корректная привязка двух picturebox друг ко другу и к границам формы

Tags: winforms

Ширина каждого пикчербокса равна половине ширины формы. Требуется сделать так, чтобы при изменении размера формы ширина пикчербоксов изменялась соотвественно и чтобы пикчербоксы не налезали друг на друга. Я пробовал использовать Anchor и Dock, но ничего не помогает.

[image: pictureBox1 и pictureBox2]

Answer (score 0):

Для этого два пикчербокса следует заменить одним splitcontainer и с помощью anchor закрепить его по всем четырем направлениям.